# Call dart function in angular controller initialization

Tags: angularjs, dart, dart-js-interop

I try to call a dart function in an AngularJS controller initialization, but I get `ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`.

#### index.dart

```dart
import 'dart:js';

myDartFunction() {
  return 42;
}

main() {
  context['myFunction'] = (JsObject exchange) {
    exchange['output'] = myDartFunction();
  };
}
```

#### My html with AngularJS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <p>{{var}}</p>
    </div>
    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="../packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("MyApp", []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
            var exchange = {};
            myFunction(exchange);
            $scope.var = exchange['output'];
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems to me, that `context['myFunction']` has not been set yet, when controller gets initialized. How can I wait for it and initialize `$scope.var`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that it is possible to use `window.onload`, which is called after my dart function has been exported to JS. Then I use [$scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) to change my scope variable.

```
angular.module("MyApp", []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    window.onload = function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            var exchange = {};
            myFunction(exchange);
            $scope.var = exchange['output'];
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to fire an event from Dart after the function was created and execute the code in JavaScript as event handler for this event.

Comment: What kind of event would you fire? Which code would you execute in the event handler? Where can I listen for the event, having access to my angular variable?

Comment: You can just call `dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('dart-ready'));` (not tested but as far as I remember it should look like this). In JavaScript you can do something like `document.addEventListener('dart-ready', doSomething, false);`

Comment: All right, but how can I access my angular variable in `doSomething`?

Comment: You make a Dart function availabe to JavaScript (like you did with `myDartFunction`) which returns the value of the Dart variable you want to access from JS.

Comment: Maybe there is any misconception. I would like to initialize the **angular variable** (`var` used in `<p>{{var}}</p>`) with the result of a **dart function call** (`myDartFunction`). If I call `dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('dart-ready'));` after `context['myFunction']` has been set and listen in my JavaScript code with `document.addEventListener('dart-ready', doSomething, false);`, I can call `myDartFunction` via `myFunction` in `doSomething`, but I do not know, how to assign the result to `var`, because I do not know how to access `var` in `doSomething` (outside of angular).

Comment: If your event handler `doSomething` is a function of your `MyCtrl` controller this should be quite easy. I don't know Angular.js though and can't tell if this involves some difficulties there.

Comment: This was the hint I needed. I have to call `$apply`. A typic beginner's mistake.